# JVector map How to change the size of tooltip which are shown when mouse cursor is over region

Tags: javascript, jquery, jvectormap

I'm using `JVector Map` plugin .I want to change the size of texts which it shows (in a black tooltip) the name of regions after hover them.

here is my Javascript code if nedded:

```
 $('#world-map').vectorMap({
    map: 'world_mill',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    zoomOnScroll: false,
    regionStyle:{
        initial: {
            fill: '#878787',
            "fill-opacity": 1,
            stroke: '#fff',
            "stroke-width": 1,
            "stroke-opacity": 1
        },
        hover: {
            "fill-opacity": 1,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            fill: '#133060'

        },
        selected: {
            fill: 'yellow'
        },
        selectedHover: {

        }
    },
           markerStyle: {
        initial: {
            fill: '#F8E23B',
            stroke: '#383f47',
            r:10
        }
    },

  markers: [
  { latLng: [61.524010, 105.318756], name: 'Russia' },
  { latLng: [60.128161, 18.643501], name: 'Sweden' },
  { latLng: [35.861660, 104.195397], name: 'China' },
  { latLng: [37.090240, -95.712891], name: 'USA(Neda Shine)' },
 { latLng: [56.130366, -106.346771], name: 'Canada' },
  { latLng: [-25.274398, 133.775136], name: 'Austrlia(Neda Shine)' },
  { latLng: [51.165691, 10.451526], name: 'Germany' },

  ],
  onRegionTipShow: function (e, el, code) {

      el.html(el.html() + ' (test)');
  }

});
```

here is my map I want to change style for this black tooltip which in this picture  mouse is hover for united states and it shows name of this region.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

it solved by add css style in this line :

onRegionTipShow: function (e, el, code) {

```
      el.html(el.html() + '<p id="popop">test</p>').css("fontSize","25px");
  }
```